# Python simplify if and loop

Tags: python

Our code reviewer is telling me that flag in the code below is bad and I need to refactor code in a "Python-like" style. I really can't understand how I can avoid this flag usage, here is a sample of code:

```
flag = false
for (i in range(2,4)):
   zoom()
   if (check_condition()):
      flag = true
      break

if (flag):
   tap()
else:
   raise Exception("failed")
```

I can see the only way to make a tap inside if. In this case I will have to add a return statement inside a loop, which is not the best idea from the code style point of view, isn't it?

So maybe someone can suggest a better way to organize this code?

Comment: Not related to the flag, but when you are reviewing: isn't `for i in (2, 3):` better?

Comment: yes, it is just misspelling, of course it had to be for i in (2,4)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `else:` statement with the `for` statement. It's only executed if the loop finishes normally, instead of exiting with `break`

```
for i in range(2, 4):
    zoom()
    if check_condition():
        break
else:
    raise Exception("failed")

tap()
```

Comment: Yes, it was a case. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need the falg here either, if you just call the `tab()` method instead of changing the flag value to true. It will work the same.

```
for (i in range(2,4)):
   zoom()
   if (check_condition()):
      tab()
      break
else:
   raise Exception("failed")
```